# Call a function created in the application (Python) from within an Html file

Tags: python, html, function, external

Please, I would like to know how I would run a python function that takes two parameters from within an "html" - this function is inside a class ("python" file).

Example:

**utils.py**

```
...
    def get_calc(val_old, val_inc):
        return val_old + val_inc
```

**index.html**

```
{% load static %}
    ...
    {{ get_calc "1" "3" as datawowdelay }} <= this is correct

    <div class="container">
        <h2>{{ datawowdelay }}</h2> <= this is correct
    </div>
    ...
```

My thanks for the help

Comment: I think what you're looking to do can somewhat be achieved using [custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags) - otherwise you could have your Django view function could pass the output of get_calc  to index.html

Comment: Thank you very much my friend, I answered below:

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much for your help and feedback.

I tried to use the "Custom template" previously, but it didn't work either!

The function is not exposed so that it can be used or accessed from within an **"html"** page, see this:

### **utils.py**

```
from django import template

register = template.Library ()

@register.simple_tag
def get_calc (val_old, val_inc):
    return val_old + val_inc
```

---

When referencing the function in the **"html"** file, the error below occurs:

Invalid block tag online 45: '**get_calc**'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

---

So, I tried to add a load.

### **index.html**

```
...
<body>
    {% block content %}
        {% load utils %}
    {% endblock %}
```

And also

```
...
<body>
    {% block content %}
        {% load static utils %}
    {% endblock %}
```

Returns the error:

**'utils' is not a registered tag library**

At the end of it all, if I remove what I'm trying to do, the page is successfully rendered in the browser. And on this same page I have a "for" that scans the contents of a list and assembles and builds several items using "Django Phyton" syntax.

Just the question of trying to call a function and passing parameters that doesn't work at all.

Thank you very much for any help.